# What kind of asp.net Routing is this, and how can i get it to work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, webforms

I'm trying to use the following routing which is used in the procject for other routings, but i cant get a hang of it.

```
<route name="GarageDetails" url="garage/car/details/{CarId}" physicalFile="~/Garage/GarageCarDetails.aspx">
        <constraints>
          <add placeholder="CarId" pattern="\d+"></add>
        </constraints>
      </route>
```

In my GarageCarDetails i'm trying to fetch the querystring with

```
CarId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["CarId"]);
```

but the request wont get it at all.

If i use anchors with GarageCarDetails.aspx?CarId=xxx it works fine.

My links now should look like /garage/car/details/xxx

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RouteData.Values["CarId"]` instead of `Request.QueryString["CarId"]`.

**[RouteData.Values Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routedata.values%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**: Gets a collection of URL parameter values and default values for the route.

Comment: So, is the constraint, pattern right? Do i need a <defaults>?